# Switching theme only for checkout

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to use a different theme completely for the checkout page for example? I know this can be done for products, categories and pages using the built-in scheduled design change mechanism in the admin, but what about other sections, like My Account, Cart and Checkout?

I'm thinking an observer could do it, but I have no idea which. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those, you can use event `layout_load_before` By using you can Swith theme at checkout.

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Devamitbera\ChangethemeAtCheckout\Observer;
>
> use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
>
> class ObserverforChangeTheme implements ObserverInterface
> {
>      /**
>      * Design package instance
>      *
>      * @var \Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface
>      */
>     protected $_design;
>     /**
>      * Store manager
>      *
>      * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
>      */
>     protected $_storeManager;
>   protected $request;
>   protected $logger;
>     public function __construct(
>         \Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface $design,
>       \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,   
>       \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
>       \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
>   ) {
>         $this->_design = $design;
>         $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
>        $this->request = $request;
>         $this->logger = $logger;
>       }
>
>     /**
>      *
>      * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
>     {
>       $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
>       //$this->logger->info($this->request->getFullActionName());
>       if($this->request->getFullActionName() =='checkout_index_index'){
>           $this->_design->setDesignTheme(1); // Theme id
>       }
>   }
>
> }
> ```

**Note that code is not tested:**

You can get theme id from  database table **`theme`**. Here i have set Magento  theme `Magento Blank`.

[image]

Full module at git https://github.com/devamitbera/Magento2-extension/tree/master/Change%20Theme%20at%20checkojt

Comment: Seems like a good start, but unfortunately, it looks like the default theme's layout configuration are still executing. Only the front-end resource paths are changing.

Comment: Is it works?..Please

Comment: In the end I couldn't make it work using the layout_load_before event, but it could be working in a newer version. Instead I used layout files override.